# Java Cross Platform File Operations

Tags: java

I developed a software in netbeans + Ubuntu and then converted the runnable .jar file of netbeans to .exe file using a converter software. 
I used:

```
File f = new File("./dir/fileName");
```

which works fine in Ubuntu but it gives an error in Windows, because the directory pattern of both OSs are different.

Answer (score 4):

Absolute paths should not be hardcoded. They should be read e.g. from a config file or user input.

Then you can use the NIO.2 File API to create your file paths: `Paths.get(...)` (java.io.File is a legacy API).

In your case it could be:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("dir", "fileName");
```

Answer (score 2):

> I used: `File f = new File("./dir/fileName")` which works fine in Ubuntu but it gives error in Windows, bcz the directory pattern of both os are different.

It is presumably failing because that file doesn't exist at that path.  Note that it is a relative path, so the problem *could have been* that the the path could not be resolved from the current directory ... because the current directory was not what the application was expecting.

In fact, it is perfectly fine to use forward slashes in pathnames in Java on Window.  That's because at the OS level, Windows accepts both `/` and `\` as path separators.  (It doesn't work in the other direction though.  UNIX, Linux and MacOS do not accept backslash as a pathname separator.)

However Puce's advice is mostly sound:

1. It is inadvisable to hard-code paths into your application.  Put them into a config file.
2. Use the NIO2 `Path` and `Paths` APIs in preference to `File`.  If you need to assemble paths from their component parts, these APIs offer clean ways to do it while hiding the details of path separators.  The APIs are also more consistent than `File`, and give better diagnostics.

But: if you do need to get the pathname separator, `File.separator` is an acceptable way to get it.  Calling `FileSystem.getSeparator()` may be better, but you will only see a difference if your application is using different `FileSystem` objects for different file systems with different separators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use File.separator as you can see in api docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: java.io.File is a legacy API. The NIO.2 File API should be preferred.

Comment: @Puce This is dogmatic. The reasons for legacy argument do not affect `File.seperator`. And if you think you can improve the answer it is better to edit the answer (title of the edit-button is **revise and imrpove this post**) and not mark it as not-useful (title of downvote).

Comment: @PeterRader Less dogmatic than trying to share state of the art approaches. File is a legacy API like Hashtable, Vector, java.util.Date, Calendar etc. and should generally be avoided in new code. The edit function is not good if you have to rewrite the whole answer, IMHO.